# Python - Present all files within a specific folder without the given folder

Tags: python, directory, os.walk

Using Python, I want to print all the files inside a given directory, without display the directory itself. I tried to use os.walk but it always print the directory.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for subFile in files:
            print os.path.join(root, subFile)
```

I used the directory 'DummyFolder/testFolder'

It prints:

```
DummyFolder/testFolder/folder1/folder2/file.txt
DummyFolder/testFolder/folder1/folder2/file2.txt
DummyFolder/testFolder/folder3/file3.txt
```

I want it to print:

```
folder1/folder2/file.txt
folder1/folder2/file2.txt
folder3/file3.txt
```

How can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Just print `subFile` instead of `join`ing it with the `root` that you don't want.

Comment: That will print me
file.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

Without the subfolders they are in.
I want only the directory I entered in the function to be omitted.

Comment: Right, sorry. You need a part of `root` for subdirs and `relpath` as suggested is indeed the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.path.relpath` to get path relative to your directory.

```
print(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, subFile), directory))
```